# Turing instability in social networks

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-modeling

I'm doing research on this topic from Mathematical modeling. I was wondering if anyone could recomend any literature that can help me with this. All I need is application of this model on social networks (I think that it can be used to model information flow in social networks).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Talk about your knowledge so far might help.

Comment: I know all theoretic aspects of this model. I need some literature of its application on social networks.

Comment: I find odd that you know of all the model, but know no example. Yet a quick web-search got me no examples as you wanted, so, +1.

Comment: It's used to model animal coat patterns. What I'm looking for isn't really the same as this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: By "this topic," you mean "Turing instability"?

Comment: Yes. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean only human social networks? I noticed this [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0111) with the aim of application (still rather theoretical, perhaps) to interactive behaviour amongst bacteria. its possible the bibliography might contain some useful lead for your search?

Answer (score 0):

Googling on "social networks turing instability" turned up various hits, including [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0164.pdf) and [this one](http://dl.uncw.edu/etd/2010-1/pokud/derickpoku.pdf).  They might give you leads on where to look.